# how to get all default tracing in win forms like in web api

Tags: c#, azure, trace

I want to know if someone can help me how to get the same default tracing in winforms app with dotnet 4.7.2, like we get in a .netcore webapi app, where without need to manually trace every request and dependency, once I connect to application insights, its get traced all request and dependencies etc. automatically without need to write any code.

I try to add the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer` nuget package, but the  `applicationInsights.config` file not get created and the traces not happen, if someone can help me it will be appreciated

Comment: `applicationInsights.config`  will be included  when we add `Application Insights Telemetry`.If you don`t find it, you can add it in the root directory of your Application.

Answer (score 2):

To get the default tracing using Application Insights, follow the below workaround which worked for me.

- Create a Windows Forms App.
- In windows Web App we do not have a direct option to  `Add Application Insights Telemetry` like in .NET Console and Framework Apps.
- In Windows Forms, add the below NuGet Package
  `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer`.

The below packages will be included by default

```cs
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector
```

[image]

And `ApplicationInsights.config` is added by default.

[image]

In `Form1.cs`, create new `TelemetryClient` like below

```
  private TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
```

Add the Instrumentation key in `AppInsights.config` from the created `ApplicationInsights` in the portal.

***Application Insights in Portal***
[image]

***My ApplicationInsights.config***

```cs
  <InstrumentationKey>Copy Instrumentation Key from Portal => ApplicationInsights</InstrumentationKey>
```

Change the `ApplicationInsights.config` properties,
`Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

[image]

If we run our application, we see some data is seen in Application Insights.

[image]

- We can even add `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender`  for Log4Net logging.

> but the `applicationInsights.config` file not get created and the traces not happen,

I have uninstalled the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer` package and deleted the `ApplicationInsights.config` file. Again I tried to install the same package, I observed that even if packages are Installed,  `ApplicationInsights.config` is not generated.

***I suggest you to create a new Windows app and add the Nuget Package to get the `ApplicationInsights.config` to get generated.***